# How to increase cellsize of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a ListView the size of each cell is very small. I thought to increase size of text so that cell size will adjust automatically. but this didnt work.

My java code is as follows:

```
   View v= findViewById(R.id.rowtext);


    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    getDir(root);

}


public void bt_Quit(View v)
{
    finish();
}

public  void back(View v)
{
    getDir(pos);

}
public  void home(View v)
{
    getDir(root);

}

private void getDir(String dirPath)
{


    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    pos=f.getParent();
    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {

    }


    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];

        if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }else{
                item.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}
```

The cellsize of List view is too small. What i want is to know how to adjust cellsize of listView?

Comment: did u used customized list view.

Comment: How to check this? i am using a class which is extending ListView Activity?

Comment: in ordinary list-view is not possible to increase the height of the list.you have to create another xml file what ever you want in row and inflate that xml in list view in run time using base adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change in your xml of listview

```
     android:layout_width="20dp"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
```

Change numbers according to ur need

Comment: no its changing hieght and width of listview what i want is to change heighnt and width of each listview cell.

Comment: Sorry just change the height and width of your child view you are using in listview....like textview or imageview etc